# Is there an image viewer that takes images on STDIN?

Tags: linux, unix, images, image-viewer

I'm looking for an image viewer that takes data on `stdin` and can be run like:

```
cat image.png | imageviewer
```

Answer (score 57):

ImageMagick's `display` program will do just that, assuming you pipe it something that it understands.

```
cat image.png | display
```

and it'll pop up a window showing that image.

Comment: On version `ImageMagick 6.8.8-1 Q16 i686 2014-01-04` I need to also pass `-` as a parameter: `$ cat image.png | display -` or `$ display - < image.png`.

Answer (score 16):

ImageMagick's `display`.

```
display < foo.png
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use feh, it's pretty fast.

```
cat image.png | feh --scale-down -
```

feh is a lightweight image viewer which is in the default repositories of many Linux distributions. It is especially aimed at command line users who need a fast image viewer without huge GUI dependencies.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit? Just mentioning a product (is that a command, product, or an expression of indifference?),  doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution. It's better to explain how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution, not just a random Google hit. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Comment: The question is very specific, I gave a specific answer. And for god sake there is a command line right above us.

Answer (score 8):

On Linux (and likely BSDs), almost all of them – if you give `/dev/stdin` as the path. This includes: `xloadimage`, `feh`, Eye of GNOME (`eog`).

```
eog /dev/stdin < "$file"
```

(Not all of them work well with special files, though. GThumb failed the test, for example.)

Comment: This doesn't work: cat graph.png | eog /dev/stdin

Comment: If we know "$file", i think we can issue eog "$file".Am I missing something?

Comment: @Naga: The `< "$file"` was an example. The point was whether the program can accept an arbitrary stream, be it a simple redirection or something more advanced (such as providing an image via stdin, a named pipe, process substitution, a socket, or a character device). The problem is that many viewers require the fd to be seekable, which only regular files and block devices are.

Comment: As @bukzor pointed out, `cat graph.png | eog /dev/stdin` fails, but `eog /dev/stdin < graph.png` works.

Comment: Is there any way to make this method work with piping (`|`) as well?

Comment: It looks like `eog` is looking up information on the file descriptor (which succeeds in the special case that it was redirected directly from a file), whereas normal Unix programs will just take the input regardless of where it comes from. So `eog` won't work for general stdin. Another program that works is `gwenview /dev/stdin` (the KDE image viewer).

Comment: As MaikoID's answer shows, `... | feh -` works.  But `... | feh /dev/stdin` fails.

Comment: `eog <(cat file.png)`

Answer (score 4):

A FIFO could work with `eog`'s lack of piping support:

```
mkfifo ${tmpfilename};
cat ${file} > ${tmpfilename} &;
eog /dev/stdin < ${tmpfilename};
rm ${tmpfilename};
```

AFAIK this should work.

Answer (score 0):

With [***imv***](https://sr.ht/%7Eexec64/imv/), e.g. on Debian bullseye:

```
sudo apt install imv

# it provides commands imv-x11 and imv-wayland
# e.g. with imv-x11, pipe to imv-x11, and make sure to end the command with a dash: e.g.

systemd-analyze plot | imv-x11 -

# "systemd-analyze plot" returns on stdout an SVG image of the systemd services/units startup timeline
```